# Remove duplicate in a linked list using js

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have tried this code, but it hasn't worked correctly. Why?

I am using the set to catch the unique elements and then check about the elements in my set:

```
this.removeDuplicates = function(head) {
    // Write your code here
    let prev = head
    let current = head.next
    let head1 = head
    let mySet = new Set()
    while (current) {
        mySet.add(prev.data)
        if (mySet.has(current.data)) {
            prev.next = current.next
            current = current.next.next;
            continue;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    return head1
}
```

Test case:

Input: 1 2 2 3 3 4

Output: 1 2 3 3 4

Output should be: 1 2 3 4

Comment: Why not debug your code (search "how to debug js code in [your preferred browser here]") and see what is actually happening? That is better than asking others to do it and then explain what they are observing.

Comment: correct, but it wasting time too, so i have asked for a hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check following code:-

```
this.removeDuplicates = function(head) {
    //Write your code here
    let prev = head
    let current = head.next
    let head1 = head
    let mySet = new Set()
    while (current != null) {
        mySet.add(prev.data)
        if (mySet.has(current.data)) {
            current = current.next;
            prev.next = current;
            continue;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    return head1;
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65613535/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 0):

```
this.removeDuplicates = function(head) {
    //Write your code here
    let prev = head
    let current = head.next
    let head1 = head
    let mySet = new Set()
    while (current) {
        if(prev.data == current.data){
           prev = current;
           current = current.next;
           continue;
        }
        mySet.add(prev.data)
        if (mySet.has(current.data)) {
            prev.next = current.next
            current = current.next.next;
            continue;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    return head1
}
```

Comment: gives error on line current = current.next.next;

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65613526/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).